# C++ - declaring an array with values of non-consecutive indexes only

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I would I combine

```
string test[8];
test[3] = "Bar";
test[7] = "Foo";
```

into one single declaration?
Maybe something like `string test[8] = {3: "Bar", 7: "Foo"};`?

Comment: Can't be done. Arrays don't have "empty" spaces. But maybe if you describe the problem you're actually trying to solve someone might be able to come up with an alternative.

Comment: Yes, sounds very XY-ish. And like you need to use a map

Comment: It can have `""` blanks

Comment: But why do you need to have `Bar` and `Foo` at specific locations in  your array?

Comment: Does your compiler really accept `string test[];` without a number between the brackets?

Comment: like `{"", "", "", "Bar", "", "", ", "Foo"}`

Comment: @fredoverflow you're right, it should be `string test[7]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a fan of `std::array`? Then you could do something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T, unsigned n>
std::array<T, n> sparse_array(std::initializer_list<std::pair<unsigned, T>> inits)
{
    std::array<T, n> result;
    for (auto&& p : inits)
    {
        result[p.first] = std::move(p.second);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto test = sparse_array<std::string, 8>({
        {3, "Bar"},
        {7, "Foo"}
    });
    std::cout << test[7] << test[3] << '\n';
}
```

Although I don't really think the additional complexity is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you want to specifically use an array you just have to declare one bigger than you need. You can manually allocate more data, but you probably want some other data structure.

```
string test[8];
test[3] = "Bar";
test[7] = "Foo";
```

You could also do a map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    map<int,string> aMap;
    aMap[3] = "Bar";
    aMap[7] = "Foo";


}
```

Edit:
here is a map reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is so dangerous. Imagine that you want something like:

```
string test[];//this is not valid the
test[3] = "Bar";
test[99999] = "Foo";
```

Since arrays are consequence data, it will allocate(99999+1) item in the memory which is absolutely not the right way of doing it.

You may either use map:

```
std::map<std::size_t,std::string> test;
test[3] = "Bar";
test[7] = "Foo";
```

In this case, only two items of `pair` have been allocated in memory.

If you need a static allocation you may use this:

```
std::array<std::pair<std::size_t,string>,2> test={{3,"Bar"},{7,"Foo"}};
```

See @fredoverflow solution it has very nice way to treat your array.